# Is copying sheet data localy better for memory consumption than link cells to external file

Tags: excel, vba, memory-management, import

I'm currently working on an excel sheet that is filled by operator on a machine.

Since the files are open from a server, there is some RAM efficency issues with the Excel calculation, and since i'm a student engineer, and not a computer program guy, i dont know how to mesure the impact of different types of coding.

I was wondering if copying my reference sheet every file opening with something like (note that this is not real code it's for explaining the logic behind it):

```
Sub workbook_open()
If ThisWorkbook.("Reference sheet") <> \\Referencefile.xlsx("Reference Sheet")
Copy-paste on ThisWorbook.xlsx the data from Referencefile.xlsx
End Sub
```

Was more Ram efficient than having for exemple this :

```
='\\Reference\[Referencefile.xlsx]Reference Sheet'!A98
```

In my cells.
(Note that the "referencefiles.xlsx" is a 30k lines monster that takes quite some seconds to open already.)

Having the "Reference sheet" data copied localy(same file instead of external file) would make my calculation "local" too, which i suppose would make my code lighter server RAM wise.
But on the other hand, having to compare huge data sheets every opening seems heavy Ram wise too.

If there no "Exact" answer, is there a way to calculate memory consumption of a code with code line?

Thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy you have to open both workbooks and then move the data from one place to anther. This could result in having 2 copies of the same data in memory for a bit. After the copy operation is complete it would be the same as having them both open. I believe the direct reference would be faster because it avoids the extra copy step.

You can verify this by using resource monitor:
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/use-resource-monitor-windows-10

Then perform both of your tasks and see the difference.